# Unknown jar depency fails the build process

Tags: java, maven

On a maven project when i do:

`mvn -X org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline --settings settings.xml`

I get the following error:

```
...

conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=1680103, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=89159}
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=21692, ConflictMarker.markTime=7902, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=2333, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=8092, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=25150, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=786197, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=75859}

...

[WARNING] The POM for jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.12 is missing, no dependency information available
conflictItemCount=2, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=4173501, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=91642}
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.253 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-07T00:22:03+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline (default-cli) on project demo: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure to find jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.12 in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline (default-cli) on project demo: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure to find jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.12 in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

...
```

In my `pom.xml` i have no such dependency. There is no mention of `jcifs:jcifs:jar` anywhere in my project. I also tried `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and `mvn dependency:tree -X` both of which do not have `jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.12` in the output. Any ideas on how i can track down what's going on?

### POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.au.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <metrics.version>2.2.0</metrics.version>
        <jersey.version>1.17.1</jersey.version>
        <jackson.version>2.1.4</jackson.version>
        <dropbox.version>0.6.2</dropbox.version>
        <powermock.version>1.6.4</powermock.version>
        <rabbitmq.version>3.6.6</rabbitmq.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.6.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropbox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${dropbox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jdbi</artifactId>
            <version>${dropbox.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-db</artifactId>
            <version>${dropbox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-migrations</artifactId>
            <version>${dropbox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-client</artifactId>
            <version>${dropbox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${dropbox.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-views</artifactId>
            <version>${dropbox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.49</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>${rabbitmq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>timestamp</item>
                    </items>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.cosium.code</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-code-format-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- On commit, format the modified java files -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-formatter-hook</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-hooks</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: try grep for `jcifs` in output of `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Can you please post your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: sure. added the pom.xml

Comment: @MarcinWasiluk tried that. `mvn dependency:tree` has no mention of `jcifs` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if i upgrade the following to latest version then my issues is resolved:

```
from:

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7</version>
</dependency>

to

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `jcifs:jcifs:1.3.12` in the mvn repo.
Can you try replacing or adding the mvn dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: which repo do you pull it from? I get this with my current repo settings. 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline (default-cli) on project bronte: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure to find jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.12 in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: it seems whatever package that needs jcifs, needs that specific version (1.3.12)!.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your project is not able to download the dependency. Try to do a force update.

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Comment: Add these two lines in properties tag and try to do mvn clean install.          <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>

Comment: Bit strange.. I tried with your pom dependencies and I was getting the same error but it went away for me once I updated maven compiler version.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to identify which pom it is referring. Your project must not be configured properly or corrupted.

Try invalidate cache and restart

Then do `mvn clean install`
Post that go to `File => Maven => Synchronise`

or

use command `mvn -U idea:idea`. This will refresh complete cache.

Comment: i tried, no luck. I blow up the entire mave. ~/.m2/repository folder too but it gets stuck at the same point.